# Initializing a class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode-scanner

I am trying to detect a barcode scanner input using jquery and javascript. I found this class that I can use in stackoverflow:

```
class BarcodeScaner {
  initialize = () => {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', this.keyup)
    if (this.timeoutHandler) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandler)
    }
    this.timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
      this.inputString = ''
    }, 10)
  }

  close = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.keyup)
  }

  timeoutHandler = 0

  inputString = ''

  keyup = (e) => {
    if (this.timeoutHandler) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandler)
      this.inputString += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
    }

    this.timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.inputString.length <= 3) {
        this.inputString = ''
        return
      }
      events.emit('onbarcodescaned', this.inputString)

      this.inputString = ''
    }, 10)
  }
}
```

To intialize the class and add an event handler, I did:

```
bc = new BarcodeScaner();

bc.initialize();

$(document).on( "onbarcodescaned", function(inputString) { 
  alert(inputString)
});
```

However, when I scan a bar code I do not get an alert. I also do not get any error messages.

Comment: `events.emit('onbarcodescaned', this.inputString)` is causing `Uncaught ReferenceError: events is not defined`  (because `events` is not defined)

Comment: Are you sure your scanner is configured to emit keyboard events?